# Upgrade Evolution in 14.04? No PPA and overwhelming dependancies to build

Tags: apt, gnome, ppa, evolution

Is it reasonable to install a current version of Evolution (say 3.16.1) on Ubuntu 14.04?  I added the recommended 'ppa:fta/gnome3', but I'm still only offered 3.10.4 from the Ubuntu archive.  It seems the ppa currently only supports Vivid and Utopic.  I downloaded the tar for 3.16.1, however building this on Trusty seems onerous.  I run './configure', read the failure message, google for the package containing the failed dependency, install the package, and repeat.  I've one-by-one installed several packages already and don't feel like the end is in site.  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  It looks like at one time the ppa offered '3.13.7-fta1.2~trusty'.  Is there a way for me to get that package?  Or was it removed because it didn't work?

Comment: You can get a lot (probably all) of dependencies by `sudo apt-get build-dep evolution`.

Comment: `E: Unable to find a source package for evolution` -- Does this imply I have some configuration error?

Comment: Uncomment all lines starting with `deb-src` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update` and continue with `apt-get build-dep` as suggested.

Comment: That gets me further, however now I'm stuck with `No package 'libedataserverui-1.2' found`...is this a loosing battle? I can't find any package that contains it, not to mention the other version issues like `Requested 'camel-1.2 >= 3.16.1' but version of camel is 3.10.4`  Should I expect to be able to succeed without heroic effort?

Comment: @proximous you'll probably want to try after removing the PPA. It seems to be causing problems.

Comment: removed the ppa and did an update.  Same issue. To be clear, the first issue is `checking for EVOLUTION_DATA_SERVER... no`. Then I get the errors like wrong version of camel, libebook, libecal, libedataserver, libebackend, and no package libedataserverui.  Do I need to add a ppa to get newer versions of these items and the missing libedataserverui?