# Adding software source of "archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu Wily Main" in Trusty Tahr

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, evolution

I have ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS installed I would like to upgrade from evolution 3.10.4 to 3.16.5, I can install it from `ppa:fta/gnome3` but I want to install the official build.

for this I have added this line in software sources,

```
archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu Wily Main
```

But I don't know whether it is safe or not. Before this, I tried to install evolution 3.16.5 manually but it has a lot of dependencies which can not be installed from **trusty main**.

How can I upgrade evolution to 3.16.5 without upgrading other packages except dependencies?

Comment: You will just break your system.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/613679/upgrade-evolution-in-14-04-no-ppa-and-overwhelming-dependancies-to-build?rq=1

Comment: That's why I thought it would be better to ask before action.

Comment: @ElderGeek I tried that, but camel-1.2 >= 3.16.1 dependency could not be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remove the Wily repo now!

*Quickly* before something does an automatic upgrade and you end up with a system that is completely boned.

Evolution relies on dozens of Gnome packages and systems so upgrading one will need you to upgrade another, which will need you to upgrade another. Do you see what I'm saying? You'll need to upgrade most of Gnome.

Because of all the dependencies, it's also pretty hard to compile *just* the bits you want. Again, you'll end up upgrading most of your system.

So with that in mind I can only suggest:

- Waiting two months for Xenial
- Upgrade to Wily (via Utopic and Vivid)

Comment: I thought the same when synaptic shown me number of packages to remove or upgrade, So I canceled the installation.

Comment: Could you please share your experience or anyone else's who broke the system by adding and upgrading sources of next build ? I am curious :-).