# Getting latest version of evolution on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, evolution

How do I install the latest version of Evolution on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

I have tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fta/gnome3  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

This installs Evolution 3.10.4

This works fine but I want a later version that supports google tasks

Comment: Did you first remove the older version of the software?

Comment: You can also download the new version from http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Communications/Email/Evolution-Devel-18873.shtmland use gdebi to install

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee that seems to provide a download for the source code for 3.19, it would be much better to download the offical source from Gnome itself https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613679/upgrade-evolution-in-14-04-no-ppa-and-overwhelming-dependancies-to-build) - looks like building from source will be difficult due to dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions [here](http://linuxpitstop.com/how-to-upgrade-evolution-email-client-to-3-16-on-ubuntu-15-04/):

```
sudo apt-get remove evolution
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

are for 15.04 (vivid) (and 14.10 (utopic)) - no packages are available in the PPA for 14.04 etc, so the package manager falls back on [the version provided in the ubuntu repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/evolution):
[image]

The problem is that Gnome programs generally is they depend on other parts of Gnome to work properly - since 14.04 uses Gnome 3.10 as a base version it becomes difficult to install some Gnome programs for 3.8, 3.12, 3.16 etc as they may break as they don't have the right libraries etc available (unless patched) - and trying to install those libraries which in turn probably will break Unity and other Gnome apps.... see [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell).

You can get [Evolution 3.16](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily-updates/evolution) in 15.10 Wily, and if you wait two weeks you can get [3.18](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/evolution) in [16.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) (also a LTS like 14.04, but still in beta currently).

If you really want to, you can try installing the packages for 14.10 *(**may break stuff, I recommend backing up Evolution's data before doing it**)* by adding the a different entry for the PPA:

```
sudo apt-get remove evolution
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fta/gnome3/ubuntu utopic main'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

This will try and install the packages for 14.10 , which might work...

Comment: I tried this and got "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming."

Comment: Could you post the full error (you can use https://paste.ubuntu.com/), and which command were you running. Its not working either because it can't find other packages it needs to install (dependencies), or because you need to [remove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) the old PPA first

Comment: I have already removed the new PPA and re-installed Evolution 3.10.4 If I only have to wait two weeks for a resolution there does not seem much point in pursuing this furthur. However if the results would help others I will have another go